# (2003 Dodge Ram1500 hemi) My idler pully snapped off while driving

Tags: dodge, ram, pulley

I went to look at it and it cut through the bolt and what the idler pully is connected to. What is the idler pully connected to?

Comment: That pulley will normally be bolted to either the block or a significant bracket...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair, BTW!

Answer (score 1):

It could be one of two places in your serpentine belt drive. This is the front of your engine.

Look at pulley's #5 & #9:

[image: Pulled from Google Images]